# Amazon S3: How to restrict bucket access to anything other than my Android mobile App

Tags: android, security, mobile, amazon-s3

I have an Amazon S3 bucket containing mp3 music files, the files are "public_read" accessible, the bucket policy is allowing everyhting to be read.

The music should be accessible from my streaming website along with my mobile App.

For streaming from within website, I use Cloudfront RTMP, I can restrict bucket access to the bucket to be only accessible through the RTMP distribution, and I can also restrict buckt access to only my http reffrer (my website), but this way, the music will not be reachable by my mobile App (http straming), I tried spoofing "referer" header in the mobile App, but this did not work.

I would like to know how to grant access to my files to only my website and my mobile App and deny everything else. (For the website I think RTMP or Referer solution will do the job)

If the above is not possible, is there a good solution for RTMP streaming with Android/IOS ?

Comment: If you solved this problem, can you please share solution?

Comment: No, sorry, and thnk you if you will do it when you find a solution.

Comment: Any solution for this problem?

Comment: @birdcage No :-/

Comment: Please let me know too if you find a solution for this.

Comment: @Artist404 hello, unfortunately no

Comment: @YahyaYahyaoui Did you check with Amazon for the same? I have added a separate issue on the Github, if you find any thread please share. Thanks

Comment: @Artist404, No, I did not checj with Amazon, ok thanks, the same, if you find something can you pease post it as an answer ?

Comment: sure, you can follow this link here https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/issues/202

Comment: Hi, Do we have any solution for this? I ran into similar situation on how to provide access only through my mobile APP.

Comment: @Karthik Hello, I did not look again into it, but I am still interested on it, I will get back here if I could find something soon